# Why does using an arrow function instead of direct function call produce different results in Mocha js test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a function in some nodejs code like this:

```
function myFunc(input){
    let somevar = otherFunc(input);

    //do a bunch of stuff
}
```

When I write my tests in Mocha I have noticed something I don't understand.

Version 1:

```
//this won't work

var sourceCode = require('../mysourcecodefile.js');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('myFunc function', function(){
    it('throws an exception if the input does not exist', function(){
        let input = idontexist;
        assert.throws(
            sourceCode.myFunc(idontexist),
            /.*my specific error message text.*/ //won't be found
            );
    })
})
```

Version 2:

```
//this will work

var sourceCode = require('../mysourcecodefile.js');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('myFunc function', function(){
    it('throws an exception if the input does not exist', function(){
        let input = idontexist;
        assert.throws(
            () => sourceCode.myFunc(idontexist),
            /.*my specific error message text.*/ //will be found
            );
    })
})
```

In Version 1 there is an error from `otherFunc()` that gets thrown first, so the regex `/.*my specific error message text.*/` does not match.

In Version 2 for some reason it seems like `otherFunc()` is skipped, and `myFunc()` correctly throws its own error that matches `/.*my specific error message text.*/`.

What is happening in Version 2, and why does it work when Version 1 fails?

My best guess is that Version 2 is using arrow functions to pass an anonymous lambda function through the Mocha framework, which somehow tells it to auto mock any subfunctions and I guess just skip them? Is this something Mocha or javascript does under the hood?

Comment: `sourceCode.myFunc(idontexist)` executes your function immediately and passes the return value to `assert.throws()`. `() => sourceCode.myFunc(idontexist)` is a callback that `assert.throws()` can execute when it needs to

Comment: Does `do a bunch of stuff` reference `this`?

Comment: Consider this: `() => 1` and `1` are not the same. The first one is a function, the second one is a number. Read the Mocha.js documentation to learn what `assert.throws` expects as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks, @SebastianSimon which documentation do you recommend? I'm not finding it on https://mochajs.org/api/ or on https://mochajs.org homepage.

Comment: @phoenixdown Wherever `require('assert')` comes from.